# How do I pass data to my WFP callout driver?

Tags: windows, winapi, networking, firewall, wfp

I have a WFP callout and a filter operating at the `FWPM_LAYER_ALE_BIND_REDIRECT_V4` layer.

I would like to be able to pass some data into this callout (such as an IP address) so that my callout driver may make use of it.

I have tried using "provider contexts" but without much luck, the `pFilter->providerContext` pointer is always `NULL`

How do i pass data to my WFP callout driver?

Comment: Maybe you should check your code. And [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41843edc-0140-4b7a-ab1d-b2c4b335401e/sharing-data-in-wfp?forum=wfp) can give you some help.

Comment: @JeffreyShao-MSFT I did get it working in the end - strangely i didn't change my code at all, it just started working. I have no idea why. But now i can't get it NOT to work. I'm just going to put it down to a momentary blip in the cosmos. By the way, are MSFT docs and the forum not being maintained anymore? It was a total nightmare getting this working, the only way was to read through the example code - which is written at an extremely high level of abstraction with so many intermediary helpers that it's hard to see the forest for the trees.